# Parse HTML with BeautifulSoup replaces existing HTML tag

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using `BeautifulSoup` v4 to parse out a string of HTML that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head></head>
<body><p>Hello, world</p></body>
</html>
```

Here is how I am parsing it:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Where `html` is the pasted HTML above. For whatever reason, BS keeps replaces the `<html>` tag with a standard tag without the extra meta info. Any way I can tell BS to not do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out by passing in `html5lib` as the HTML parser to BS. But, now, it keeps dropping in a random HTML comment tag for the `DOCTYPE`

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE HTML-->
```

Comment: This is due to the fact that BeautifulSoup treats `<!DOCTYPE` as a comment type